# My instance is accessible from ipv4 address and public DNS. I want it to be accessible from domain name only

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, wordpress

I just installed WordPress on Amazon AWS (EC2 Instance)

The problem is that my instance is accessible to public from both ipv4 address and domain name i asssigned to it through DNS. Like for testing purpose i used

decodewithdude.ga

The domain is accessible from http: //13.233.253.149/

https://ec2-13-233-253-149.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com

https://decodewithdude.ga

Is it normal or should be worried about it?

Can i make it accessible to public only from domain name?

Thankyou

Comment: What web server are you using? Nginx, Apache, or something else?

Answer (score 6):

This is normal behavior of web servers that have virtual host concept.

You need to set up a default virtual host in your webserver that returns for example `404` to every request.

Then your website is defined in a virtual host that has your domain in it.

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: Look into your web server's documentation how to configure virtual hosts.

Answer (score 0):

Create a different virtual host, either don't give it any content or redirect where you want, and then make it the default (usually by being the first virtual host configuration file).